# Unfortunately, program has stopped. FATAL EXCEPTION: main, java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

i have a problem, im trying to program Accelerometer, with charts, but when im running app i got these error, Unfortunately, program has stopped  :

```
    Process: com.example.egnasz.myapplication, PID: 7963
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.egnasz.myapplication/com.example.egnasz.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.ref.WeakReference.get()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.lang.ref.WeakReference.get()' on a null object reference
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
                      at com.telerik.widget.palettes.ChartPalettes.dark(ChartPalettes.java:108)
                      at com.example.egnasz.myapplication.MainActivity.createChart(MainActivity.java:212)
                      at com.example.egnasz.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:111)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)
```

how to fix it?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final int X_AXIS_INDEX = 0;
    private static final int Y_AXIS_INDEX = 1;
    private static final int Z_AXIS_INDEX = 2;

    private int defaultCoolDown;
    private int coolDown;

    private int bufferSize;
    private int currentAxisIndex = X_AXIS_INDEX;

    private int framesCount = 0;
    boolean stopped = true;

    private SensorManager sensorManager;
    private Sensor accelerometer;

    private ViewGroup chartContainer;

    private RadCartesianChartView chart;

    private Queue<SeismicDataPoint> seismicActivityBuffer;
    private List<SeismicDataPoint> allSeismicActivity;

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (this.stopped || this.coolDown-- > 0) {
            return;
        }

        this.coolDown = this.defaultCoolDown;
        if (this.seismicActivityBuffer.size() > this.bufferSize) {
            this.seismicActivityBuffer.remove();
        }

        SeismicDataPoint point = new SeismicDataPoint(this.framesCount++, event.values[this.currentAxisIndex]);

        this.seismicActivityBuffer.add(point);
        this.allSeismicActivity.add(point);

        this.chartContainer.removeAllViews();
        this.chart = createChart(seismicActivityBuffer);
        this.chartContainer.addView(chart);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // hide the actionBar
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getActionBar().hide();

        // To be tweaked for performance on different devices
        Resources resources = getResources();
        this.defaultCoolDown = Integer.parseInt(resources.getString(R.string.default_cool_down));
        this.bufferSize = Integer.parseInt(resources.getString(R.string.buffer_size));

        this.coolDown = this.defaultCoolDown;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        this.accelerometer = this.sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

        this.seismicActivityBuffer = new LinkedList<SeismicDataPoint>();
        this.allSeismicActivity = new ArrayList<SeismicDataPoint>();

        // Adding points to fill the screen at initial state.
        for (int i = -this.bufferSize; i < 0; i++) {
            this.seismicActivityBuffer.add(new SeismicDataPoint(i, 0));
        }

        this.chartContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.chart_container);

        this.chart = createChart(this.seismicActivityBuffer);
        this.chartContainer.addView(this.chart);

        Button startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_btn);
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stop();
                stopped = false;
            }
        });

        Button stopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_btn);
        stopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stop();
            }
        });

        Button resetBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset_btn);
        resetBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // The activity is forced to landscape, so X and Y are different in phone and tablet devices.
        final RadioGroup axisSelectionMenu = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.axis_selection);
        axisSelectionMenu.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.axis_x:
                        currentAxisIndex = X_AXIS_INDEX;
                        break;
                    case R.id.axis_y:
                        currentAxisIndex = Y_AXIS_INDEX;
                        break;
                    case R.id.axis_z:
                        currentAxisIndex = Z_AXIS_INDEX;
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("there are only 3 axes");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        this.sensorManager.registerListener(this, this.accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.sensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }

    private RadCartesianChartView createChart(Iterable<SeismicDataPoint> dataPoints) {
        RadCartesianChartView chart = new RadCartesianChartView(this);
        LinearAxis vAxis = new LinearAxis();

        // The maximum value of the accelerometer is 20 and the minimum -20, so give a bonus 10 to the vertical axis.
        vAxis.setMaximum(30);
        vAxis.setMinimum(-30);

        CategoricalAxis hAxis = new CategoricalAxis();
        hAxis.setShowLabels(false);

        DataPointBinding categoryBinding = new DataPointBinding() {
            @Override
            public Object getValue(Object o) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                return ((SeismicDataPoint) o).x;
            }
        };

        DataPointBinding valueBinding = new DataPointBinding() {
            @Override
            public Object getValue(Object o) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                return ((SeismicDataPoint) o).y;
            }
        };

        LineSeries series = new LineSeries();
        series.setCategoryBinding(categoryBinding);
        series.setValueBinding(valueBinding);
        series.setData(dataPoints);

        CartesianChartGrid grid = new CartesianChartGrid();

        chart.setGrid(grid);
        chart.setVerticalAxis(vAxis);

        chart.setHorizontalAxis(hAxis);
        chart.getSeries().add(series);
        chart.setPalette(ChartPalettes.dark());
        chart.setEmptyContent("");

        // Customize chart elements after adding them to the chart to override the application of the palette.
        hAxis.setTickColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        grid.setMajorYLinesRenderMode(GridLineRenderMode.INNER_AND_LAST);
        vAxis.setLineColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        return chart;
    }

    private void stop() {
        this.stopped = true;
        this.chartContainer.removeAllViews();
        this.chart = createChart(this.allSeismicActivity);
        this.chartContainer.addView(this.chart);
    }
}
```

SeismicDataPoint:

```
public class SeismicDataPoint {

    public int x;
    public float y;

    public SeismicDataPoint(int x, float y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.egnasz.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/side_menu">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start"
            android:id="@+id/start_btn" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Stop"
            android:id="@+id/stop_btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:id="@+id/reset_btn" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/axis_selection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/axis_x"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="X-axis"
                android:checked="true" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/axis_y"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Y-axis"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/axis_z"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Z-axis" />
        </RadioGroup>

    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/chart_container"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/side_menu"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.egnasz.myapplication">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.egnasz.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile (name: 'Chart-2016.3.914-trial-release', ext: 'aar')
    compile (name: 'Common-2016.3.914-trial-release', ext: 'aar')
    compile (name: 'Primitives-2016.3.914-trial-release', ext: 'aar')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: and how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you tell me what is your `"@style/AppTheme"` ?

Comment: Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar, is this right theme?

Comment: or im wrong? when im pressing on that letters in manifest it nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want `ActionBar` in your `Activity`, you can remove the following lines from your code:

```
// hide the actionBar
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
getActionBar().hide();
```

And replace the parent of your `AppTheme` with:

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar
```

Comment: ok i will try and i will tell then if it works!

Comment: I still get error Unfortunatey, program has stopped!;/

Comment: The logs must be different this time, show me the new logs.

Comment: So, i just needed to make dissapear action bar? Because logs ar the same as was..;/

Comment: The crash log you posted in your question point to the line I suggested you to remove, the crash logs cannot be the same because those lines are not a part of your code or is it?

Comment: so i need just remove those lines?

Comment: Yes remove those lines and change the theme as I mentioned.

Comment: ok ill tel what will happens after that

Comment: ok i deleted those lines, but i got same error "Unfortunately, app has stopped", and same error lines FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.telerik.demo.seismograph, PID: 10843
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.telerik.demo.seismograph/com.telerik.de etc...

Comment: The way you read a crash log is reading these lines: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.hide()' on a null object reference
  at com.example.egnasz.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:91)

Comment: The code that was causing the crash, isn't there anymore, so the logs must have changed, and you need to debug that now.

Comment: yes you are right, now i getting another log, if you can look at it, i just edited my question:)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your AppTheme parent by `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` (and delete lines from `getWindow()` to `.hide();`, or use the following method `getSupportActionBar().hide();`, because since you're using `AppCompat`, `v4.Toolbar` is replaced by `v7.Toolbar`, and as `getActionBar()` returns `v4.Toolbar`, you can't use it.

Comment: ok i will try and i will tell then if it works!

Comment: I still get error Unfortunatey, program has stopped!;/

Answer (score 0):

Extend you `activity as AppCompatActivity` and then use action bar as:-

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();  // for hiding
getSupportActionBar().show();  // for showing
```

hope it helps

Comment: ok i will try and i will tell then if it works!

Comment: I still get error Unfortunatey, program has stopped!;/